# I am using jmeter currently and i have a response which returns a value as 348.0 which i will forward to another request

Tags: regex, jmeter, response, beanshell, reply

I am using jmeter currently and i have a response which returns a value 348.0 which i will forward to another request. but i want the value to be forwarded as 348 only with the decimal and digits gone how can i achieve this i have tried many things but it doesn't seem to work. i know i should use beanshell here but i am not able to get it right.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While there are a dozen people to help, we still need some code and an exact question.

Comment: I have used regex(\u003e@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)@(.+?)") to capture a value from a response and store it in a variable named supposedly Abc. I used the varible as ${Abc_g5} to pass the value to the new request, but before passing on the value to the request i want to remove the decimal from the value(348.0)and pass it(348) on further. how can i achieve this?

Comment: please read this; [ask], [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in order to [round()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Double.html#round()) or [truncate()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Double.html#trunc()) the value like:

```
${__groovy((vars.get('myVar') as double).round(),myVar)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Mathematical Functions and Converting Data Types in Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mathematical-functions-and-converting-data-types-in-groovy)

Comment: I changed my regex which finally solved the issue thanks everyone for helping